# Where can I find what `export` does internally in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, export

I have been using the `Barrel files` strategy to have one single file with several `export` from the same folder. Then it's easier and cleaner to import one single file than each of the other imports.

I was wondering what does `export` do internally? and if using it could lead to some performance problems in a Flutter App.

Comment: `export` tells the Dart compiler how to resolve symbols.  It should have no ultimate effect on the generated code and therefore should not affect runtime performance.

Comment: thanks @jamesdlin is there any reference to read more about those internals? I'd like to explore it.